# Does liferay CE 7 support Java 9?

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, java-9, portal

Has anyone tried Liferay 7 tomcat8 bundle with **Java 9** ?
Is it supported?
If not, which version of Liferay CE portal  supports Java9 and above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer for GA is no, in any meaning.

Long answer is : if you are using Liferay CE GA bundles up to 7.1.1 (GA 2) with tomcat, as suggested by the tag, Liferay did not had the proper metadata to run on java 9 and the bundles would not start (in tomcat it would just stop).

The next bundle in line, GA 3, added the ability to run on Java 11, meaning that features of Java 11 might be present and this would make Java 9 an issue as "bugs" may emerge, especially those dynamically generated code components or those compiled when needed. Additionally, if you are using bundles, they may carry JVM options from Java 11 that do not exists on Java 9, in such case the vm would not even start without turning those.

**If not, which version of Liferay CE portal supports Java9 and above ?**

- Regular tomcat bundle: 7.1.2 (GA3) -> Java 11 and above only, not 9
- Docker based: https://hub.docker.com/_/esystemstech

Answer (score 0):

You can check [the compatibility matrix](https://www.liferay.com/services/support/compatibility-matrix) for Liferay EE (or DXP), which gives a good hint at what Liferay CE requires to run. As of "support", it depends on what you mean: The only commercial support that is offered by Liferay (the company) is on the Enterprise Offering (DXP).

The basic principle is that Liferay CE and DXP are only tested on the LTS-versions of Java. Currently that's 8 and I believe 11 is coming soon. However, Liferay CE 7.0 might not see a formal update in case it requires some changes for Java 11 compatibility, as Liferay CE 7.1 is the branch that currently gets the updates.